# Microsoft Office 2010 start page numbering on page 5

Tags: windows, microsoft-word

This is driving me absolutely insane. I want to start the page numbering on page 5 and for it to continue to the end of the document. I've tried using page/section breaks but that didn't work. I've also tried pressing ctrl + F9 while in the footer and adding it in the format { if{ page } < 5 "{ page *roman }" "{ page }" } but that doesn't work either.

Does anyone have any ideas? I've been trying to fix this for the past hour.

Answer (score 2):

In order to have different page numbering, you need a couple settings correct:

1. You'll need the section breaks – I don't think Page Breaks are adequate (you can choose to have your section start on the next page through the page setup/layout tab), and
2. On the header/footer design tab, make sure that the "Link to Previous" option is disabled.
3. Format your page numbers to start at the right number (I'm not sure if your fifth page is really page 5, or is it page 1?)

Answer (score 1):

I fought with this for ages looking up answers on tons of websites to no avail and gave up. So, what I did was use paint. I reduced the screen size in paint to just the size of the words I needed in the header, typed the words and made it a light gray colour so it would look like it does in the header. I then inserted the picture into the document, selected 'through' on 'word wrap' under 'picture tools' and was able to move the my picture header to exactly where I needed. A very annoying complicated problem solved in a creative way.

Answer (score 0):

I believe using the [section break option](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/insert-a-section-break-HA010368780.aspx) should allow you to do this - you create a section break before the page you want page numbers to start with